# Romex Split connection kit

Tags: electrical, wiring, connectors

Short question: Are Romex splice kits for 14/2 approved for use in Ontario Canada?

Long question: I’ve put in a new ceiling (drywall and tongue/groove pine) in my kitchen. I’ve installed multiple pot lights however, when cutting the holes for the pot lights I inadvertently cut a hole in the wrong spot. This spot is about 5 feet from where I planned to put the SD (Smoke Detector), so I would like to use this spot for the SD. I’d like to splice the wire from the originally planned SD location (I’ve not yet drilled the hole for the SD but can reach the wire from one of the other pot light holes) to where I inadvertently cut the hole for a pot light. I can't use the box where the pot light is because it is an LED with a too small junction box to accommodate another set of wires.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: What is a "SD"?

Comment: Can you put in a standard depth junction box, make the splice there, then attach the LED to the standard junction box? Or does the new light have some sort of proprietary mounting that will only allow it to connect to the box that comes with it?

Answer (score 1):

Your ‘authority having jurisdiction’ can tell you if the splice kit is acceptable to them. It should be, as those kits usually need to be somewhere that’s able to be fished (as opposed to permanently buried).

I’m not really understanding why you can’t install a conventional junction box and do a normal splice, though. This could just be behind a blank cover or you may be able to find a light that attaches to a box.